# regex pattern for a unique string in a bunch of very similar strings

Tags: regex, python-3.x

[image]

Here is the text file which I am given. I am reading the .txt file line by line, and I want to extract the gene name (RAF in this case). However, gene name is not necessarily three letters long and doesn't necessarily contain letters. It can also contain letters and digits e.g "SPATA72K", "HER2". How do I extract Gene-Name provided the format of .txt file is always the same?

Comment: Don't post screenshots post this in text format

Comment: Not for python, but on unix, you can try  sed 's/\S\S*\s\s*\(\S\S*\)\s.*$/\1/' . This will work or not, depending on the details of your format. This is assuming you want the second entry, separated by white-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'awk' for this.You will be able to get the gene names filtered. Hope it helps you.

```
awk '$(column no.)~/^regex$/' file
```

Comment: I have a python script in which I need the gene name since it is related to some other functions. is there a way to do it in Python?

Comment: @osaama.s I don't know about python, but regular expressions seem to be mostly the same as for unix sed. awk, on the other hand, is often awkward.

Comment: @osaama.s Yes you can. There are two ways: 'subprocess'  or 'os.system'. Check the manual first. If possible you can preprocess the file to get the gene name then feed the result to the desired function. It is up to you how you want to do it.

Comment: @biozid bostami how do I capture the output from subprocess?

Comment: Check the manual of the official guide. I am giving you the link below:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html